# Secure streaming in wowza media streaming

Tags: android, ios, https, wowza, rtmps

I am having a wowza server setup and I am able to play my files in iOS ans android. (vod)

Can someone suggest me how can I enable ***HTTPS*** for iOS streams and ***RTMPS*** for android streams.

As a preliminary steps I have generated my self signed certificate.( I dont know how to use it with wowza server)

please Help me to achieve that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured vhost.xml file?

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?128

Comment: I was able to achieve it by editing vhost.xml (You replied little late :D). Anyway Thanks hope it helps other people.